# Difference between an independent claim and a dependent claim for same thing

Tags: claims, claim-construction

Is there a difference in patentability, scope, or protection from infringement between the two cases of claims below?

case 1
I claim:
1 A piece;
  a hole in said piece.

case 2
I claim:
1 A piece.
  The piece of claim 1 with a hole.

Comment: I’m not a lawyer, but I’m pretty sure you need to add something to a dependent claim. This dependent claims are narrower. Something like: a piece according to claim 1 where the hole is between 1 and 10cm in diameter.

Comment: It is hard to determine the question from your example.

Comment: Is the case 2, a claim 1 with an independent claim?

Comment: Further to your question - you want to write the widest coverage claim as independent. Case 2 in this respect is better. The examiner will attempt to limit the coverage of your independent claim and will than force you to revert to case 1.

Comment: Thanks Moti - so the second case is broader than the first even though they both have the same claims.

Comment: If I understand your example, the second version only works if “a piece” is novel and not obvious on its own.  if it is then the second case gives you a claim 1 that is broader that the claim 1 in case 2. If you need the hole to achieve patentability then case 2 will not get you anywhere.

Comment: George, Thanks. I think you meant to say the 2nd case gives a claim 1 that is broader that the claim 1 in case 1 (not case 2). I see now that everything is considered in case 1 for patentability and that only the first part (the independent claim) is considered for patentability in case 2 and if that is accepted then the dependent claim is considered.